# Passing vector by reference is requesting std::allocator

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector

I'm using c++.

So my situation, I'm attempting to pass a vector by reference to a function. Before building, the compiler throws an error at the function call:

```
no instance of function matches the argument list
argument types are (std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>)
```

If I create the project in Visual Studio as a Console application, this works fine and throws no errors. If I create the project as a Desktop application, it throws this error. I would prefer sticking with a desktop application.

Any help or comments would be great, thank you!

Here is a sample of code that is throwing the error

```
Definition

VOID SomeFunction(vector<int>& MyVector)
{
...Do something with the vector
}


Call

vector<int> vect;
vect.push_back(1);
//The error is thrown here
SomeFunction(vect);
//
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with an [mre] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Welcome! I agree with @NathanOliver, anyway it sounds like you have an issue with your namespaces, maybe you should decorate with "std::" the struct you are using. Anyway, better example code would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies! I made a quick reproducible example in a main file and it actually worked fine. I don't think my error is with the vectors, but with translation between cpp files and headers. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting my code has shown that this was an issue in a define statement in the project, not the compiler or c++, thanks for the help :)